# Set struct array in C

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, struct, command-line-arguments

I am writing a simple struct array program. A string is given and I want to parse it. A string consists of few characters.

For example, A string "a:bc:D:E"  has 5 unique characters.  Colon ":" tells that that character has a value.

Struct array size is 256 ((option[256])) which includes all ASCII characters.

From given string, I want to find the characters and fill the struct array with value “1” at their ASCII position. If character is not present in the string then assign the value “0”.

Further I want to set “hasVal" filed of this struct. For example,  a = 1 (has colon in the given string), b = 0 (no colon after "b" in the string), c =1, D = 1, E =1.

Lastly, print this structure as shown in the expected output.

I am not very good in programming. I just started learning C language. I tried this but i am not getting expected result. I apologize if I am not able to convey my problem statement.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

sample.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 256

typedef struct {
  int hasVal;
  char *defaultVal;
  char *desc;
} validOpt;

validOpt option[MAX_CHAR] = {};

char *optStr = "a:bc:D:E";


int main() {

int i;
for(i = 0; *(optStr + i); i++)
{
    /*  Not Sure how to check this....
     * check the "char" and ":",
     * if both are present, set the field "hasVal" to 1 or "0".
    */
    if((optStr[i]++) == ":")
        option[optStr[i]--].hasVal = 1;
    else
        option[optStr[i]--].hasVal = 0;

}
printf(“Printing structure…\n”);
printf("\n");
for(i=0; i< MAX_CHAR; i++)
{
    if(option[optStr[i]].hasVal == 1) {
           printf(" %d -- %c\n", i , option[optStr[i]].hasVal);
    }

 }

return 0;
}
```

Actual Output:

```
[rock12/C_Prog]$ ./sample
 Printing structure…
```

Not getting anything after this line.

Expected Output:

```
 1) If user enters invalid character, give an error. 
  For Example, "q" -> not valid option

 2) For Valid options, print:
    a - 1
    b - 0
    c - 1
    D - 1
    E - 1
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not a good problem description. What does it do that you don't expect? What does it not do that you do expect? How have you tried to debug it? What results have you gotten?

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchwartz for your help and time. I can not print the structure. I simply want to parse the string and find the characters and assign value to struct members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(option[optStr[i]].hasVal == 1) {
    printf(" %d -- %c\n", i , option[optStr[i]].hasVal);
```

This condition is not enough. You need to distinguish between characters which appear and don't appear in the string, and the characters which have or don't have values.

You need an additional variable, for example `is_shown` to figure out if the character occurs or not.

```
#define MAX_CHAR 256
```

`char` range is from zero to 128. In your example it seems it is sufficient to go from `A` to `z`. But let's keep it at 128.

```
for(i = 0; *(optStr + i); i++)
{
    if((optStr[i]++) == ":")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

There is an error above. When you reach the last character in the string you increment once more to check the next characters, it goes over bound.

Modify the code as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    int is_show;
    int hasVal;
    char *defaultVal;
    char *desc;
} validOpt;

#define MAX_CHAR 128
int main()
{
    validOpt option[MAX_CHAR] = { 0 };
    char *optStr = "a:bc:D:E";
    while (*optStr)
    {
        char ch = *optStr;
        option[ch].hasVal = 0;
        if (ch != ':')
            option[ch].is_show = 1;

        if (*(optStr + 1))
            if (*(optStr + 1)== ':')
                option[ch].hasVal = 1;

        *optStr++;
    }

    printf("Printing structure\n\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        if (option[i].is_show == 1)
            printf(" %c -- %d\n", i, option[i].hasVal);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
 D -- 1
 E -- 0
 a -- 1
 b -- 0
 c -- 1
```

You have to sort it to get it the way you want. Note that `E` is not set, because there is no `:` after `E` which is the last character.

---

Edit: Alternate method:

use `malloc(strlen(optStr) * sizeof(validOpt))` to create `option` array and fill it. In this case `option` has array size 8, it only needs array size 5. It's more efficient.

```
typedef struct {
    char ch;
    int hasVal;
} validOpt;

int main()
{
    char *optStr = "a:bc:D:E";

    //option's array size is always larger than optStr's size, so it's safe
    validOpt *option = malloc(strlen(optStr) * sizeof(validOpt));

    int i, count = 0, len = strlen(optStr);
    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        if (optStr[i] == ':') //ignore this character
            continue;
        option[count].hasVal = optStr[i + 1] == ':';
        option[count].ch = optStr[i];
        count++;
    }

    if (optStr[i] != ':') //handle the last character in optStr
    {
        option[count].hasVal = 0;
        option[count].ch = optStr[i];
        count++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf(" %c -- %d\n", option[i].ch, option[i].hasVal);
    free(option);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> ```
>  a -- 1
>  b -- 0
>  c -- 1
>  D -- 1
>  E -- 0
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmak. Appreciate it! You saved my lot of time. It worked perfectly fine. Need to study more array and structure related programs. Let me know if you have some good references.

Comment: No problem, I was bored so I added a second method to solve it.

Comment: Cool. Btw in second approach, if I want to declare string and struct array globally, it might create a compile time issue. This only works if I declare them locally.

Comment: No, you can declare them globally. However it's best to avoid global variables, instead pass pointers to the variables through functions.

Comment: Yes. That is true.

Answer (score 1):

First, in the end of your main, you try to printf `i` as a `char`, and `option[...].hasVal` as an `int`, isn't it inverted?

Instead of doing `*(optStr + i)`, do `optStr[i]`. It is EXACTLY the same, and much more readable.

Then, option is an array of validOpt.
By doing this:

```
option[*(optStr+i)] = 1;
```

`*(optStr+i) == optStr[i]` is a char, so it's an ascii value.
You then try to assign a validOpt to 1. You can't. Because validOpt is a structure. Maybe you want to do `validOpt.hasValue = 1`.

In fact, I don't fully understand what you want to do here, if you can develop a little bit more it would be great :)

Comment: Thanks @Ludonope. I tried to modify program based on your comments. But I still can't achieve my result. I have given Expected result. I simply want to parse string and fill struct array based on characters in that string.